# Properly broadcasting events to specific directive element using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add some UI features to my application and am not sure about the best way to do so.  I have 2 tables on a page, one called Active and one called Inactive. The Inactive table has a `<td>` that contains a button to add it to the Active table. There is an API call involved so I want to disable the button and make the entire `<tr>` for that button have an `opacity: 0.4`.  I tried adding a directive to each row and then using `$scope.$broadcast` I emit the event that the button was clicked.  The problem is that this emits the event for EVERY `<tr>` in my table instead of just the one that I activate using the button.

What would be the proper way to bind this relationship between a button click and the `<tr>` DOM element getting CSS changes?

```
<tr ng-repeat="active in Dataset sk-row>
   <td>{{ active.Customer }}</td>
   <td style="text-align:right"><input type="button" class="btnPlain" value="Add to Backups" ng-click="activateBackup(active)" /></td>

</tr>
```

**activateBackup function**

```
 $scope.activateBackup = function (itemData) {

        $scope.$broadcast('removedFromTable');

}
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('skRow', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$on('addedToTable', function (event, data) {
                elem.css('backgroundColor','#fff');
                elem.animate({
                    'backgroundColor':'#000'
                }, 1000);
            });

            scope.$on('removedFromTable', function (event, data) {
                elem.css('opacity', '0.4');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Please provide aplunkr or jsfiddle. Rgds

Comment: I want this effect on all tables in my application so I don't want to define the template of the `<tr>` within my directive because it changes based off of the table

Comment: I have a pretty good idea what your problem is. Before I post a reply though, can you post your HTML markup for both the active and inactive tables?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, a simple `event.stopPropagation()` should solve your problem.

```
scope.$on('removedFromTable', function (event, data) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  elem.css('opacity', '0.4');
});
```

**UPDATE**
As your activateBackup $broadcasts from the parentScope, I suggest sending the whole event data along and manually check it in your listener function.

```
$scope.activateBackup = function (itemData) {
   $scope.$broadcast('removedFromTable', itemData);
}

<tr ng-repeat="active in Dataset" sk-row="active.whateverIdentifier">...</tr>

scope.$on('removedFromTable', function (event, data) {
   if(data.identifier === attr['sk-row'])
      elem.css('opacity', '0.4');
});
```

Comment: Well the thing is `activateBackup` is just on my controller `$scope` and so when it `$scope.$broadcast`s the event, how does just the specific `<tr>` row know to change opacity? In the DOM there are tons of `sk-row` directives, so it is unclear on what one has to be modified

Comment: That's what I expected. In this case your best chance is to send the whole data with the event and check it in the listener.

Comment: Ok thats what I was afraid of haha.. Instead, I think I will just make this directive for this specific table row and then I can use the directive's `link` scope to set the opacity and then call the parent controllers `activateBackup` function. That seemed to work ok

Comment: I also would go with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to fire an event in the opposite way i.e. using `$emit()`.

```
$scope.activateBackup = function(itemData, itemScope) {
  itemScope.$emit('removedFromTable');
};
```

and pass the `itemScope` using `this` in `ng-click` like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="active in Dataset" sk-row>
  <td>{{ active.Customer }}</td>
  <td style=" text-align:right ">
    <input type="button" class="btnPlain " value="Add to Backups " ng-click="activateBackup(active, this)" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Unlike `$broadcast`, when using `$emit`, you could call `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
scope.$on('removedFromTable', function(event, data) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  elem.css('opacity', '0.4');
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/9YH4VFfHUvsqKPHw9Ida?p=preview

Comment: Ah That is a good idea. I didn't realize you could emit the event across that specific scope